# How do you express two plural nouns separated by 'and'?

Tags: word-usage, plural-forms

I am always confusing plural forms of nouns.

A - "Cats and Dogs"
B - "Cat and Dogs"

If two words are plural, which one is correct?

As I understood, there is no special situation for that, it seems: Plural is plural, singular is singular in English. The second one is correct in my native language; that's why I got confused, sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both words 'cats' and 'dogs' are plural then 'A' option is correct!

> A - "Cats and Dogs"; this shows more than one cat and more than one dog.

While:

> B - "Cat and Dogs"; this shows single cat and more than one dogs.

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking for the plural of "cat and dog," that is "cats and dogs." "Cat and dogs" would mean there are one cat, and more than one dog.